# Algorithm to find power station on a 2d grid

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, grid, distance

[image: http://i.imgur.com/v21Hnjb.png]

As the image shows, there is a 2d grid with Homes and PowerStations. Figure out an algorithm to find closest power station for each home. 
I know how to write the brute force one, with the complexity O(m*n), in which m is the number of homes and n is the number of power stations. But could anyone give a better solution? (Can assume power stations are regularly located in this way)

Comment: I'm curious about your brute-force O(m*n) algorithm (it seems, some factor is missing). One (theoretical; maybe not practical) approach: use Floyd-Warshall to calculate shortest paths O(V^3) of all pairs and look for the solution in O(m*n) time.

Answer (score 1):

If your input is the grid, do a BFS.

First, insert in the queue all power stations. Then proceed the BFS as usual with one slight modification: you must remember from which initial power station each added square was accessed.

Using this algorithm, you'll reach each house naturally with the closest power station.

The complexity is `O(s^2)`. Where `s` is the side of the grid.

Comment: The input is one list of homes with coordinates, and another list of power stations with coordinates. It's something like {home: [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]}, {PS: [[2, 2], [2,7]]}